# Python unittest for a function that reads from a buffer

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a function in python which waits for a reply / message from another program.
The function extracts the message from the buffer incrementally and stores the message as a string in memory.
I want to unittest this function (the way it reads from the buffer and reconstructs the message as a string).

What I have:

```
Input of function: Example message to be read.
Output of function: Expected string.
```

How can I 'mock' the buffer in my unittest?

Comment: I realize my question is a little vague. So I would also appreciate any links to relevant documentation.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you provide runnable code that illustrates the function in question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.